# How do i enable client_credentials worflow enabled for my LinkedIn application?

Tags: linkedin-api

I was told my LinkedIn support to post this question here. How can my linkedin app get approval to use the Client Credentials workflow as stated here

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow

Comment: Hi, did you get an answer on this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).